# Java Stream Updating running total

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have following java lines of code, i am wondering if it can be totally converted to Java 8 Stream fashion?

```
long totalSum = list.parallelStream().mapToLong(ExpenseInfo::getCurrCount).sum();

// LOOP ALL COLLECTION
for (ExpenseInfo info : list) {
    totalSum -= info.getCurrCount();
    info.setBurnCount(totalSum);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that your task is sequential by default. For example, the first element will have its burn count set to the total sum minus its own count while the second element will have its burn count set to the total sum minus its own count and the count of the previous elements and so on.

That is, if you would have to turn this sequence of instructions using a stream and that the stream would be parallel (using `.stream()` or `.parallelStream()` should have no consequence on the result you compute), the totalSum variable would be shared and every element in the ordered stream would have to wait the updated value of the total sum computed by every previous element, which would defeat entirely the purpose of using parallelism.

That said, you can use another approach that would first map each instance to its own curr count and then use `Arrays.parallelPrefix` to compute the cumulated sum into an array.

Finally, you can use an `IntStream` to set the burr count of each element by subtracting the total sum and the cumulated sum for that element.

```
long[] sums = list.stream().mapToLong(ExpenseInfo::getCurrCount).toArray();
Arrays.parallelPrefix(sums, Long::sum);
IntStream.range(0, sums.length).forEach(i -> list.get(i).setBurnCount(sums[sums.length - 1] - sums[i]));
```

Of course, it supposes that the list is random access so that `get(int i)` is not an expensive operation, but everything can be parallelized without problems (in fact `parallelPrefix` is already parallelized, as its name suggests).

I would still keep your approach in first place, it seems clearer to me.